# How do I find my DBET tokens in MyEtherWallet?

Tags: tokens, myetherwallet

I mistakenly bought DBET tokens directly from my Exodus wallet. I used the public key of Decent.bet (DBET). I assume I should be able to find/see my DBET tokens in MyEtherWallet, but I do not know which steps to take. Hopefully, someone in here can clarify this for me.

Answer (score 0):

With [MyCryptos latest release yesterday](https://twitter.com/MyCrypto/status/996460059822456832), scanning for your tokens is much easier and faster due to the upgraded process of showing your token values.

1. Go to MyCrypto (local copy or the website) and safely unlock your account.
2. [Scan for your tokens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oigzy.png) on the right side of the UI
3. You can now interact with the token (i.e: sending) in the middle part of the UI.

If the DBET token doesn't appear, it may not be [added as a default](https://github.com/ethereum-lists/tokens), so you'll have to add a custom token to the interface. With MyCrypto, this is a pretty easy flow - [kb article](https://support.mycrypto.com/tokens/token-creators-add-your-token-to-mycrypto.html)

Once you've scanned for your tokens, click the "Save" button. Now that view partial will have a [new button called "Add Custom Token"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZD3D.png). From here, we can grab the [token details from Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/token/0x9b68bfae21df5a510931a262cecf63f41338f264) or from the dev team in Slack/Telegram/Discord/etc.

For DBET, the values are;

- **Token Symbol:** `DBET`
- **Address:** `0x9b68bfae21df5a510931a262cecf63f41338f264` (this is the token contract address)
- **Decimals**: `18`

[image]

Once you've saved, MyCrypto will automatically rescan your token values and you can interact with the tokens.